# Is there a Math.PI equivalent that returns a float?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I'm writing C# apps where I want the value of PI as a float, not a double. Currently I cast the value from double to float and end up with ugly (float) Math.PI casts all over the code.

Is there a built in PI function that returns a float?

**EDIT:** Why use a float instead of a double? I'm using a LOT of floats, and crunching a lot of numbers so smaller data == more fits in cache == better performance.

Comment: @AVD, is right. const float fPI = (flaot) Math.PI;

Comment: curious as to why you need less precision?  The normal approach is to perform calcs at the higher precision and cast the final answer, rather than casting the intermediries

Comment: You should think about putting that in an answer, @Mitch, it's worth an upvote.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, for example XNA is using float calculation for performance reason, assign to float is just a single instruction (atomicity) and he may just want to support some old code.

Comment: @MitchWheat because I don't need the accuracy but I do need the performance gains from using floats over doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Starting with .NET Core 2.0 (.NET Standard 2.1)** and upper Microsoft give access to using float type without hacks by including default `Math` constants and methods into **`MathF`** class of `System` namespace with all arugments and return types as floats.

Example usage:

```cs
using System;

class Class
{
    public void Method()
    {
        float floatPi = MathF.PI;
        float floatSin = MathF.Sin(floatPi * 2);
    }
}
```

For further information see [documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.mathf?view=netcore-3.0) about `MathF` type.

Answer (score 8):

Not as far as I know. Just have your own constant:

```
const float PI = (float)Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers about defining a float constant are all correct.

But I'm curious as to why you need less precision?

The usual approach is to perform calculations at the higher precision and cast the final answer, rather than casting the intermediaries (which could possibly lead to accumulation of errors, depending upon the sort of calculations you are performing).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such built-in function.

If you are casting from `double` (`Math.PI`) to `float` on many occasions, store the value as float somewhere. As a static/const member in your class would be more than suitable, if the classes uses the value a lot.

Other wise you could create an object elsewhere that you use inside your own object, with the variable holding pi (as a float)  is `static`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the `(float)Math.PI cast`, why don't you write a wrapper class and property?

```
public class MathEx {

    public static float PI {
        get {
            return (float)Math.PI;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have two nitpicks here. The first is that I have no idea what a `flost` type is :-) The second is that since PI is _very_ unlikely to change, perhaps it would be better as a (const/final-type) member variable rather than a function.

Comment: I've edited 2 typos, and would love to edit those braces!  ;)

Comment: I can't believe that Jeffrey Zhao, as a Java-language hater, wrote the braces in this style!

Comment: @DannyChen: No one said the brace style belongs to Java. If you read more code like ASP.NET MVC released from Microsoft, they also use brace like this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is in XNA framework: [MathHelper.Pi Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.pi.aspx), but I bet you don't any other extra dll just for one cost - better define one in your own helper. BTW, almost always double should be choose by default.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
const float Mypi = 3.14159265358979f;
```